# Как сделать <table> по высоте 100%

Tags: html, css

Пробовал сделать `<table widht="100%" height="100%">` но не работает. Я знаю что лучше использовать div но сейчас мне нужно именно table на всю по высоте 
http://jsfiddle.net/emirM/3L9mz3qn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы задать таблице(или другому элементу) 100% высоту необходимо задать определенную высоту родительскому элементу. В вашем случае таблица лежит в элементе body. Зададим ему 100%. В свою очередь, чтобы body растянулся на всю высоту, необходимо задать 100% и для элемента html.

```
html, body{height: 100%;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3L9mz3qn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Твой вариант корректен. В примере jsfiddle высота твоей таблицы зависит от контейнера в данном случае от body. Если body увеличишь, то и таблица увеличится до размеров body.